# Class Structure in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I need to use class structure in classic asp. I have written following three classes.

Category.asp

```
<%

Class Category

    Private NameVar

    Public Property Get Name()
        Name = NameVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let Name(nameParam)
        NameVar = nameParam
    End Property

End Class

%>
```

Item.asp

```
<%

Class Item

    Private NameVar
        Private CategoryVar

    Public Property Get Name()
        Name = NameVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let Name(nameParam)
        NameVar = nameParam
    End Property

    Public Property Get Category()
        category = categoryVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let Category(categoryParam)
    CategoryVar = categoryParam
    End Property

End Class

%>
```

Test.asp

```
<%

    Dim CategoryVar
    Set CategoryVar = New Category

    CategoryVar.Name = "Weight"

    Dim ItemVar
    Set ItemVar = New Item

    ItemVar.Name = "kg"
    ItemVar.Category = CategoryVar

%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>UoM Componet Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= ItemVar.Name %><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code, I have found some problem. Error is:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01B6) Object doesn't support this property or method: 'CategoryVar'".

How can explain this? Please help me.

Comment: Did you try `Set ItemVar.Category = CategoryVar`?

Comment: i have reproduced your error, it's weird!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VBScript, if you know that a property will contain an object reference, you must define it using the [`Property Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzhy86w7%28VS.84%29.aspx) statement.  Furthermore, you must use the [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28VS.84%29.aspx) statement when assigning object references to variables.  With that in mind, the following changes need to be made:

Item.asp

```vb
Class Item

    '<snip>

    Public Property Get Category()
        ' Add Set here
        Set category = categoryVar
    End Property

    ' Change "Property Let" to "Property Set"
    Public Property Set Category(categoryParam)
        Set CategoryVar = categoryParam
    End Property

End Class
```

Test.asp

```vb
<%
    ' <snip>    

    ItemVar.Name = "kg"
    Set ItemVar.Category = CategoryVar

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your above code and, while I did get an error, it's not the one you mentioned.

First of all you are defining `Name` twice in the `Item` class, one should be `Item`. Secondly, you assign `ItemVar.Category = CategoryVar` yet the `Item` class has no `Category` Property.

Here is the code I used to test and it works fine:

```
<%
    Class Category
        Private NameVar

        Public Property Get Name()
            Name = NameVar
        End Property

        Public Property Let Name(nameParam)
            NameVar = nameParam
        End Property
    End Class

    Class Item
        Private NameVar
        Private ItemVar

        Public Property Get Name()
            Name = NameVar
        End Property

        Public Property Let Name(nameParam)
            NameVar = nameParam
        End Property

        Public Property Get Item()
            Item = ItemVar
        End Property

        Public Property Let Item(itemParam)
            ItemVar = itemParam
        End Property
    End Class

    Dim CategoryVar
    Set CategoryVar = New Category

    CategoryVar.Name = "Weight"

    Dim ItemVar
    Set ItemVar = New Item

    ItemVar.Name = "kg"
    'ItemVar.Category = CategoryVar ' There is no 'Category' property in your class
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>UoM Componet Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= ItemVar.Name %><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, the question has been edited since this answer was posted.  The typo you mention is no longer in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issues as Rory, redefining of name, and there being no Category property.

I have adjusted the code below to take into account the edited question:

Should it not be something like below?

```
Class Item      
    Private NameVar   
    Public Property Get Name()         
        Name = NameVar     
    End Property      
    Public Property Let Name(nameParam)         
        NameVar = nameParam     
    End Property      

    Private CategoryVar   
    Public Property Get Category()         
        Category = CategoryVar     
    End Property      
    Public Property Let Category(CategoryParam)         
        CategoryVar = CategoryParam     
    End Property 
End Class 




Dim CategoryVar     
Set CategoryVar = New Category      
CategoryVar.Name = "Weight"      

Dim ItemVar     
Set ItemVar = New Item      
ItemVar.Name = "kg"     
ItemVar.Category = CategoryVar.Name
```